# Phase and Symbol Timing recovery - Lock detection

Tags: pll, symbol-timing

I have a BPSK receiver that perfectly synchronizes in both phase and timing. This can be observed by looking at the convergence of Costa's loop and symbol timing recovery. My question is how to mathematically detect the lock for PLL-based algorithms (statistically or otherwise)? All the data from the Costa's (phase estimate and error) as well as symbol timing recovery circuit (fractional interval and error) are available. Below is an example of the phase estimate from the Costa's followed by error transient from the symbol timing recovery algorithm based on the M&M TED.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Costa's phase estimate]

[image: Symbol recovery]

Comment: Looks like good work Moses. All the “Lock Detection” indicators I have seen have all been subjective based on a rms phase error being below a certain threshold. Of course this rms error will itself be proportional to signal SNR, but you will have a minimum SNR requirement per your minimum desired error rate- so you could use that as a threshold for lock detection as well (the rms error out of your error detector when your input is at the minimum SNR condition— double or triple that to be your lock detect threshold)